# Trigger xDebug in PhpStorm when calling using CURL

Tags: debugging, curl, command-line, ide, xdebug

so I use CURL from the command line to make calls to my PHP website:

```
curl -s "url"
```

My question is...is it possible to modify this command so that I can trigger xDebug (combined with an IDE (I use Jetbrains PHPStorm)) when calling the site from CURL

perhaps manipulate the GET variables?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The following code works for me

```
curl -i -X POST -d '{"some":"data"}' http://your-local-domain -b XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM
```

Comment: actually, I got it to work. Previously the prob was my curl call. Thanks @wyxa!!

Comment: you shoud setup your ide key (session id) to PHPSTORM too.

Comment: didn't work for me, until I added the path as suggested on @tin-can 's answer.

Comment: In my case, I had to add `-L` option to solve "301 Moved Permanently".

Answer (score 11):

I was still having trouble until I added `path=/` to the cookie in addition to wyxa's answer.

```
curl --cookie "XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM;path=/;" localhost
```

Comment: Worked for me with: curl --cookie "XDEBUG_SESSION=14738;path=/;" localhost

Answer (score 2):

1. Install an xdebug extension in your browser, for instance, [The Easiest Xdebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/) for Firefox or [Xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en) for Chrome/Chromium.
2. Click the button of the extension to enable it, and refresh the page you're loading.
3. Open your devtools, open the "network" panel, and find the AJAX request or the main request that you're interested in. Right-click on the request, and click "Copy as cURL" in Firefox, or "Copy -> Copy as cURL" in Chrome/Chromium.
4. Now paste that command into the terminal and run it. You'll notice that the cURL command already has the cookie `XDEBUG_SESSION` set under the parameter `-H Cookie: ...`.